# redirect root domain name to amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect, dns

My domain is rather long. I need to use it without www.
All the info I find on the net is about cnames.
How do I redirect the whole domain to an amazon s3 bucket, not only a subdomain?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon [recently announced](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/12/27/root-domain-support-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/) support for root domain hosting via S3.  The instructions for setting this up can be found [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).  Note that you will have to setup two buckets to accomplish this, and that you will have to use Route 53 for your DNS hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Try [wwwizer](http://wwwizer.com/)

What you need to do is to create a cname www pointing to your s3 bucket url (bucket name will need to match) and then create an A record to the ip given by wwwizer.

Another way is to use a url redirecting service or use a free web host (like godaddy's ad supported hosting) and on the index file issue a redirect to www.yourdomain.com.

There might be other solutions that rely on finding out the ips of the amazon s3 front end servers but they are error prone.